# Can't call function with While loop two times using opencv cap

Tags: c++, opencv

I have created a function, let's call it function1, this function use a while loop to read a video with Opencv my code is very long so I add an example to explain my problem. When I call this function 2 times in the main it's stops when she finish the first call and don't execute the second call I can't figure out why. How to fix the problem and call the function 2 times.

```
void function1(param1, param2)
{
    char key = 'a';
    while (key != 27)
    {
        cap >> frameFromVideo;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    function1(param1, param2);
    function1(param1, param2)
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is `cap`? did you try to debug your program?

Comment: provide [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  and refer [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: The first call never finishes - your loop is equivalent to `while (true)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call key=waitKey(5); in the loop. Your key always equals 'a', anl loop never breaks.

Comment: @ user1810087  cap is a video capture that capture frames from a video. @Andrey Smorodov  I add 'break' if Frame is empty and it's working